# CouchDB and PouchDB plain users can create Databases

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I don't want normal users to be able to create Databases.

In the Futon Screen /_utils, when logged in as a plain user, everything functions as expected. Only Admins can create Databases.

But when I sync my pouchDB with couchDB, plain users can also create (replicate?) Database. I want the adding of new Databases only to be restricted to Admin users.

Also I just noticed that existing DB also get edited even when user is restricted.

How can I fix this?

```
var remoteCouch = http://testuser:testuser@{domain}.iriscouch.com/testdb;

PouchDB.debug.disable();

if (remoteCouch) {
    sync();
} else {
    console.log("No remote server.");
}

function sync() {
    var opts = {live: true};
    db.replicate.to(remoteCouch, opts, syncError);
    db.replicate.from(remoteCouch, opts, syncError);
}
```

**EDIT**

Testuser is also not in /_config/admins

Testuser:

```
{
   "_id": "org.couchdb.user:testuser",
   "_rev": "1-7d28b3388a62cfca103cbe3642549bee",
   "password_scheme": "pbkdf2",
   "iterations": 10,
   "type": "user",
   "name": "testuser",
   "roles": [
       "testuser"
   ],
   "derived_key": "2181a44141d6d6aa2061bb2c5c057451acc6461e",
   "salt": "2184888b099f37605feca0a22e5b6bb9"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your CouchDB in admin party mode? If it's not, then only admins should be able to create databases, whether it's via Futon or PouchDB.

PouchDB isn't doing anything special; you can simulate what PouchDB is doing by using curl:

```
curl -X PUT http://someuser:somepassword@path.to.couchdb.com:5984/somedatabase
```

Are you sure your `testuser` isn't an admin? If the user that you give to PouchDB is an admin, then yes, users will be able to create their own databases.

More info on authentication can be found here: https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication#couchdb-authentication-recipes

Comment: No the CouchDB is not in Party Mode. I fixed that. The curl -x put CMD gives an unauthorized error: you're not server admin. But replicating my pouchdb with remoteCouch to http://someuser:somepassword@path.to.couchdb.com:5984/somedatabase adds new Database.

Comment: When I look in the /_config/admins, I only see one server admin (which is not testuser). The user is only in /_users. I also edited the question with the /_user/testuser doc

Comment: When you look in the Chrome console, what do you see? You should see a normal PUT request which creates the database. It will also include all the header information to tell you what the username and password was. I'm pretty sure either the database already exists or something else is going on. PouchDB doesn't have any more special credentials than curl...

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I think I was having a Logic failure here. 

It seems, that if I am logged in with an Admin Account in Futon the users credentials in the PUT uri is being ignored. Meaning that I was actually active with an admin account instead of a plain user. What confused me was that this behavior also applied on other devices. The problem however doesn't occure anymore. So I guess this is solved now.